# Expanding top bar dropdowns during page load navigates to stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, top-bar, global-inbox

On the mobile site only, when an icon in the right side of the top bar (like the inbox or reputation icons) is clicked to expand the drop down, and the page isn't *completely* loaded yet, then instead of expanding the dropdown it just navigates to https://stackexchange.com. This happens on every site.

This is a "new" behavior in that something changed to make this happen, and it didn't used to happen. However, it's been going on for a minute, at least a few months if not closer to a year. So I'm not sure exactly when it started; it took me a while to report it.

This is a problem because, for me at least, checking my inbox when there's notifications is pretty much the first thing I do on any site, and it takes a while for the page to fully load (like *completely* load, including all scripts, images, ads, and everything else). It's also sometimes easy to miss that the page isn't loaded yet because the loading progress bars on mobile Chrome are pretty low-key.

Since it appears to be a regression of some sort, and also interferes with my normal usage on a regular basis, I'm filing it as a bug.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. In a mobile browser, visit any SE site.
2. Before the page loads, tap the inbox or trophy.

**Expected:** Dropdown appears, and site stays loaded.

**Actual:** No dropdown appears, and browser is navigated to https://stackexchange.com.

Comment: FYI, this is not new and it's not specific to mobile. It is pretty annoying though.

Comment: There is no mobile site anymore, at all, anywhere. SE removed it.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Whatever. When browsing on mobile devices. It's unique to that (so I thought until 416's comment, but I guess it just seemed that way because my desktop browsers are much faster at loading pages).

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Thanks; I swear it didn't used to do that at least a few years ago; maybe time passed quicker than I thought... :'(

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard That's a nice chain of dupes; you'd think they'd have fixed it by now. I miss the good ol' days when they were right on top of every report and then I could argue with shog9 about whether it was by design or not for a week, haha.

Comment: @JasonC you want good old days, come back to Tavern and tell us about Burning Man! :-D